# Criar uma função em C, que busque quantas vezes uma uma letra aparecee em uma string

Tags: c, string, funções, helper

Preciso fazer essa função contar quantas vezes uma letra foi dita na string. Porém, o resultado retorna sempre 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void contador(char palavra[], char letra[], int aux){
    int qntd, i;

    qntd = strlen(palavra);
    for(i = 0; i < qntd; i++){
        if(palavra[i] == letra){
        aux++;
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    char palavra[50], letra[1], aux;

    printf("Digite um palavra: \n");
    scanf(" %s", &palavra);

    printf("Digite um letra a ser encontrada: \n");
    scanf(" %s", &letra);

    contador(palavra, letra, aux);
    printf("O numero de vezes que a letra %s apareceu, foi de: %d", letra, aux);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você não está passando a [variável `aux` por referência](http://linguagemc.com.br/funcao-com-passagem-por-referencia/), por isso o valor não é atualizado no *main*.

```
void contador(char palavra[], char letra[], int *aux){

..

contador(palavra, letra, &aux);
```

---

considerando o comentário, a variável `aux` é do tipo *char*. Altere para *int* que deve funcionar:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void contador(char palavra[], char letra[], int *aux){
    int qntd, i;

    qntd = strlen(palavra);
    for(i = 0; i < qntd; i++){
        if(palavra[i] == letra){
        aux++;
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    char palavra[50], letra[1];
    int aux = 0; //detalhe: inicialize sempre a variável do contador.

    printf("Digite um palavra: \n");
    scanf(" %s", &palavra);

    printf("Digite um letra a ser encontrada: \n");
    scanf(" %s", &letra);

    contador(palavra, letra, &aux);
    printf("O numero de vezes que a letra %s apareceu, foi de: %d", letra, aux);
}
```

Comment: Agora ele até esta retornando valores, mas valores aleatórios...

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1bGc.png

Comment: Já que agora em `contador`,  `aux` é um ponteiro pra `int`, você se esqueceu de alterar o `aux++`. Corrigindo isso, provavelmente irá funcionar. De todo o modo, não me agrada essa ideia de passar a variável `aux` por referência, pois se a função da função `contador` é contar a quantidade de vezes que uma letra ocorre em uma string, essa quantidade deveria ser o valor de retorno dela e não um dos seus argumentos.

Comment: Tem outro erro em `palavra[i] == letra`, pois `letra[]` foi declarado como um array na assinatura da função `contador` e o que é pior na função `main` também. Bem, em main, `scanf` está no mínimo escrevendo dois caracteres em um array declarado para caber apenas um, em `contador`, caso se insista em usar um array, a comparação deveria ser `palavra[i] == letra[0]`.

Answer (score -1):

```
  essa funcao que faz a contaGem ,  precisa ser do do tipo int e nao void ,  e retorne aux da funcao , ex:
```

int contador( char p[] , char letra)
{
int aux=0;
// faz  a contagem em aux
return aux;
}